# How to set a style sheet that only affects the parent in PyQT?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I'm trying to customize my UI. I don't know how to make a style sheet entry pertain to anything except the parent and ALL of the children. For example I run this line:

```
self.lnchTab.setStyleSheet('QWidget { background-color: #1d1d1d ; color: #f8f8f8}')
```

And I change ALL of the elements beneath self.lnchTab to be darkish grey. I want only the self.lnchTab to be dark grey, and not the text, inputs, and buttons within it.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks for any help. Google is giving nothing useful or even near what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can give `self.lnchTab` object some *name/id* and then you can use **id-selector** in style-sheet:

```
self.lnchTab.setObjectName("myParentWidget");
self.lnchTab.setStyleSheet('QWidget#myParentWidget { background-color: #1d1d1d ; color: #f8f8f8}')
```